# Undefined reference to `MD5' g++

Tags: c, g++, gcc, c++, md5

Перерыл уже достаточно много всевозмжных сайтов и так и не нашел ответ на вопрос, что нужно писать при линковке проекта с применением openSSL чтобы он заработал с g++. Пробовал отдельно компилировать под gcc и g++ простенькие примеры использования МД5, на первом работали, а на втором нет. Прилагаю два кода, первый это тот код который я пытаюсь заставить работать с МД5 под g++, а второй это работающий код MD5 под gcc и не работающий никак под g++.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>
//#include <openssl/sha.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char site[] = "mainsms.ru";
    char message[4000];// = "GET http://mainsms.ru/api/mainsms/message/send?project=mainsms&sender=mainsms.ru&message=" +"&recipients=" +"&sign="+" HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: nixmail.ru\r\n User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; ru; rv:1.9b5) Gecko/2008050509 Firefox/3.0b5\r\n Accept: text/html\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
    int sock;
    char buf[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    struct hostent* host = gethostbyname(site);
    char a1[]="OLOLO";
    char numer[]="89608712735";
    char sing[300];//=numer+";one;qbit;"+a1+";"+"73cc0ea086e3a";//89121231234;mainsms;mainsms.ru;test;07349e954831d
    strcat(sing,numer);
   // strcat(sing,";");
    strcat(sing,";one;qbit;");
    strcat(sing,a1);
    strcat(sing,";73cc0ea086e3a");
    unsigned char hash[16];

    //strcat(s,);
    MD5((unsigned char *)(sing), strlen(sing), hash);
    cout<<hash;

  //  SHA1(hash, strlen(h), obuf);

    strcat(message,"GET http://mainsms.ru/api/mainsms/message/send?project=one&sender=qbit&message=");
    strcat(message,a1);
    strcat(message,"&recipients=");
    strcat(message,numer);
    strcat(message,sing);
    strcat(message," HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: mainsms.ru\r\n User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; ru; rv:1.9b5) Gecko/2008050509 Firefox/3.0b5\r\n Accept: text/html\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n");
    //sprintf(message," HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: mainsms.ru\r\n User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; ru; rv:1.9b5) Gecko/2008050509 Firefox/3.0b5\r\n Accept: text/html\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n",a1,numer,sing);
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sock < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(80);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = ((in_addr*)host->h_addr_list[0])->s_addr;
    if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect");
        exit(2);
    }

    send(sock, message, sizeof(message), 0);
    recv(sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
    cout << buf << endl;
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

И второй

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    MD5_CTX md5handler;
    unsigned char md5digest[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    MD5("0123456789",10, md5digest);

    for (i=0;i<MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH;i++) {
    printf("%02x",md5digest[i]);
    };

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
};
```

компилирую 
g++ -main.c -lcrypto не работает.
Второй код работает с gсс -main.c -lcrypto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Испытал Ваш код. Он у меня скомпилировался, я только добавил  `#include <unistd.h>` - он нужен для `close`. И даже запускается.

Причина, по которой, у Вас не работает - Вы неправильно компилируете. Правильная строка компиляции должна быть такая

```
g++ main.cpp -lcrypto
```

то есть, минуса перед main.cpp не должно быть и имя файла должно иметь расширение cpp (cc, cxx или c++, по вкусу), иначе g++ посчитает это сишным кодом и будет компилировать по сишному.

Comment: Спасибо, заработло.